# Modify regular expression to highlight current menu item

Tags: jquery, regex

I've got this jQuery regular expression that I got from another thread here at stackoverflow. It adds a css class to the current menu item based on the url. It looks like this:

```
<script>
            $(function () {
                // show current menu object highlighted
                var url = window.location.pathname,
                urlRegExp = new RegExp(url == '/' ? window.location.origin + '/?$' : url.replace(/\/$/, '')); // create regexp to match current url pathname and remove trailing slash if present as it could collide with the link in navigation in case trailing slash wasn't present there

                // now grab every link from the navigation
                $('nav a').each(function () {
                    // and test its href against the url pathname regexp
                    if (urlRegExp.test(this.href)) {
                        $(this).addClass('current');
                    }

                    console.log(url);
                    console.log($(this).attr('href'));
                });

            });
        </script>
```

This works great if the path is exactly like that in the link href, but I want this to apply also for sub-pages of the current menu object. This is my navigation:

```
<nav>
<ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="/Admin/Blogs" title="Blog" style="border-left: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);">Blog</a>
                </li><li>
                    <a href="/Admin/Shows" title="Shows">Shows</a>
                </li><li>
                    <a href="/Admin/StoreItems" title="Store">Store</a>
                </li><li>
                    <a href="/Admin/Pages" title="Pages">Pages</a>
                </li><li>
                    <a href="/Admin/Menu" title="Menu">Menu</a>
                </li><li>
                    <a href="/Admin/SocialMedia" title="Social media">Social media</a>
                </li><li>
                    <a href="/Admin/ImageGallery" title="Image gallery">Image gallery</a>
                </li><li>
                    <a href="/Admin/MailSettings" title="Mail settings">Mail settings</a>
                </li><li>
                    <a href="/Admin/PageSettings" title="Site configuration">Site configuration</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </nav>
```

Let's say that the path is /Admin/Blogs/Create, I want the Blog menu item to be highlighted. This is not the case at the moment.
Also if I go to /Admin (i.e. the home page), at the moment all of the menu items gets selected which is not desirable.

I really need to take time to learn regex properly some day, but I'm in a bit of a hurry with this one (school project) so if anyone could help me it would be much appreciated.

Comment: school project? 
For this case, you can use substring or string match instead of regex.
or a combination of both to simplify the reg exp.
The Start ^ symbol will be helpful in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll try to work that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work with this code:

```
<script>
            $(function () {
                // show current menu object highlighted
                var url = window.location.pathname;
                var checkString;

                // now grab every link from the navigation
                $('nav a').each(function () {
                    // and test its href against the url pathname
                    checkString = url.match($(this).attr('href'));
                    if ((checkString != null && $(this).attr('href') != '/') || (url == $(this).attr('href'))) {
                        $(this).addClass('current');
                    }
                });

            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work with Mikael's code but it wouldn't keep the link in the active state on sub pages. I got it to work with the code below. The word in the href & url that matches up to put the link in the active state had to be coded in but it works for me because 'consumer' is the folder name and all sub pages will be /consumer/page.html

```
$(function () {
       // show current menu object highlighted
       var url = window.location.pathname;
       var checkString;

        // keeps the link active on sub pages, 'consumer' is the folder in this instance and all sub pages with be /consumer/page.html 
       if (url.indexOf("consumer") != -1){
          $('#quick-links a').each(function(){
               if( $(this).attr('href').indexOf("consumer") != -1){
                    $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
               }
          });    
       }

       // now grab every link from the navigation
       $('#quick-links a').each(function () {
           // and test its href against the url pathname
           checkString = url.match($(this).attr('href'));
           if ((checkString != null && $(this).attr('href') != '/') || (url == $(this).attr('href'))) {
               $(this).parent().addClass('active');
           }
       });

   });
```